# Spring: how to initialize a property without constructor?

Tags: java, spring

I have an old class with configured constructor

```
public class Outer
{
  ...
  public Outer(OldService oldService) { this.oldService = oldService;}
}
```

I need to add new field with a new service, but can't change constructor (too many legacy code depends on it). So, I want to get something like

```
public class Outer
{
  private NewService newService; // Need injection here
  public Outer(OldService oldService) { this.oldService = oldService;}
}

@Component
public class NewService
{
    public NewService(Dependency dependency){this.dependency = dependency;}
}
```

I've tried to apply @Autowired and @Inject attributes for Outer.newService, but it doesn't help. I can create Outer.Initiate(NewService newService) method, but that's will add some s**t to the project already smelled.

So, can I inject field in Spring?

**Upd1** Outer constructor is executed manually now (like var outer = new outer(service);).

Comment: Well if you've got a lot of legacy code calling the old constructor directly, how do you expect that legacy code to populate the `newService` field?

Comment: Your `Outer` class needs to be a Spring component. If not, the autowiring won't work.

Comment: Won't you break you legacy code too if you want a new required `NewService`. Why not extend class `Outer` like `NewOuter` with constructor `(OldService oldService, NewService newService) { super(oldService); }`?

Comment: @Juan I've tried apply Autowired for the field and Component for a class - newService is null.

John, I suppose Spring DI container will populate newService even when constructor is called manually. Am I wrong?

Comment: No it won't work that way because you are creating an instance and not using a Spring Bean. You should create a `@Bean` like this:

`@Bean
public Outer outer(){ return new Outer(oldService); } `

Then you can use @Autowired to get that bean and Spring will do the rest.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza I've tried, get an error
Invalid bean definition with name 'outer' defined in class path resource [path/outer.class]: factory-bean reference points back to the same bean definition

Comment: That is maybe because you are placing the `outer` method inside the `Outer Class`.

Comment: Please check [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.m3/reference/html/creating-bean-definitions.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Outer.class is not instantiated by Spring container but by `new`, it cannot be known by Spring container. This is why, Spring cannot perform dependency injection for `NewService`.

Now, if you give instantiation of `Outer` to Spring, in addition to autowiring `NewService`, you are required to Autowire or use any spring wiring to wire `OldService` into `Outer`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use field level injection:

```
public class Outer{
  @Autowired
  private NewService newService; 
  public Outer(OldService oldService) { this.oldService = oldService;}
}
```

I'm not a fan of this method, because it makes testing much more cumbersome and hides dependencies.

Instead of this, just use a setter and annotate it with `Autowired`, which does the same thing:

```
public class Outer{
  private NewService newService; 
  public Outer(OldService oldService) { this.oldService = oldService;}

  @Autowired
  public setNewService(NewService newService){
    this.newService = newService;
  }
}
```